# ディスプレイプロファイルのパスの取得方法

Tags: java, objective-c, macos

Mac OS X で「システム環境設定」→「ディスプレイ」→「カラー」を開くと現在使用しているディスプレイプロファイル名が分かり、マウスオーバーでパスも見られます。それと同じパスをJavaまたはObjective-Cのプログラム内で取得したいのですが、どうすればよいでしょうか。

パスが分かりさえすればよく、別のプロファイルに設定したりできる必要はありません。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

自己解決しました。https://github.com/mpv-player/mpv/issues/594 等が参考になりました。

```
char* getSystemDisplayProfilePath()
{
  CGDirectDisplayID displayID = CGMainDisplayID();
  CFUUIDRef displayUUID = CGDisplayCreateUUIDFromDisplayID(displayID);
  if (!displayUUID) return NULL;

  CFDictionaryRef displayInfo =
    ColorSyncDeviceCopyDeviceInfo(kColorSyncDisplayDeviceClass, displayUUID);
  CFRelease(displayUUID);
  if (!displayInfo) return NULL;

  CFDictionaryRef factoryInfo =
    (CFDictionaryRef)CFDictionaryGetValue(displayInfo, kColorSyncFactoryProfiles);
  if (!factoryInfo) return NULL;

  CFStringRef defaultProfileID =
    (CFStringRef)CFDictionaryGetValue(factoryInfo, kColorSyncDeviceDefaultProfileID);
  if (!defaultProfileID) return NULL;

  CFURLRef profileURL;
  CFDictionaryRef customProfileInfo =
    (CFDictionaryRef)CFDictionaryGetValue(displayInfo, kColorSyncCustomProfiles);
  if (customProfileInfo) {
    profileURL =
      (CFURLRef)CFDictionaryGetValue(customProfileInfo, defaultProfileID);
    if (!profileURL) return NULL;
  } else {
    CFDictionaryRef factoryProfileInfo =
      (CFDictionaryRef)CFDictionaryGetValue(factoryInfo, defaultProfileID);
    if (!factoryProfileInfo) return NULL;

    profileURL =
      (CFURLRef)CFDictionaryGetValue(factoryProfileInfo, kColorSyncDeviceProfileURL);
    if (!profileURL) return NULL;
  }

  char path[PATH_MAX];
  bool const result =
    CFURLGetFileSystemRepresentation(profileURL, true, (UInt8*)path, PATH_MAX);
  CFRelease(profileURL);
  CFRelease(displayInfo);
  if (!result) return NULL;

  return new_strdup( path );
}
```